# Android set listItem background colour from String Array

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to programatically set the background of a list item  from a String Array? I have two string arrays one is the title for the text view and the other contains a colour reference. I have added the titles Array to an array Adapter and that is showing but now i want to change the background colour for each item in the array

heres my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
      >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

heres my code so far

```
     ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] items = {"menuItem1","menuItem2","menuItem3","menuItem4","menuItem4","menuItem5","menuItem6","menuItem7","menuItem8"};  
  String[] colors = {"#ffffff","#000000","#ffffBB","#ffffDD","#ff654d","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff","#ffffff"};   
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, android.R.id.text1, items);
        menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you want to have 2 different colors in the listview??. that is what you are trying??

Comment: yes each item in the list needs a different background colour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a custom adapter as follows:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    String data[] = null;
    String color[] = null;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] data, String[] color) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        StringHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new StringHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (StringHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(data[position]);
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color[position]));

        return row;
    }

    static class StringHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Then set the adapter of the `listView` as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, items, colors);
menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Update** Just noticed: you also need to update the layout file. It seems to be defining the id of the textview wrongly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
        >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done for 2 colors.

i have kept 2 colors string in color.xml and i have used it in the custom adapter of the listview

```
if (position % 2 == 0)

            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color1);
        else
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  custom array adapter. Extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView` to return a textview with background color according to the parameter `position`.