# Android Custom ListView Text Color is not changing

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors

I am trying to change color of text-view based on some condition. I am using solution given by Amulya Khare [Android set listItem background colour from String Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657303/android-set-listitem-background-colour-from-string-array/19657563#19657563). So now i have bit modified this code as per my requirement.

My code is below.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
String data[] = null;
String color[] = null;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, String[] data,
        String[] color) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    StringHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new StringHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (StringHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(data[position]);
    // row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color[position]));
    // holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color[position]));

    if (Code.days < 2) {
        holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if (Code.days < 5) {
        holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    if (Code.days > 8) {
        holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    return row;
}

static class StringHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
}
}
```

What i am trying to do is that if the number of days is less then 2 then text color should be RED same if it is less then 5 then text color should be YELLOW ans so on. But i am only getting YELLOW color text in text-view.

Other problem is that when i delete any of the data from the list-view all the data color changes to default color say black.

So how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try else if instead of if in your second and third condition

Comment: you should use a model class have setters and getters

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditions like :

```
if (Code.days < 2) {
    holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else if (Code.days < 5) {
    holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
else if (Code.days > 8) {
    holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: This is also not working, if i do so then same thing is happening it changes color of all data instead of any particular data.

Comment: For your conditions color for two would be yellow because it's catched in the middle else if where Code.days < 5, and color for 6 would be default because it's not handled in those if checks

Comment: what other changes i have to do to achieve what i wanted to do.

Comment: Is it true, that using conditions that way all texts are same color?

Comment: Yes of course, if your answer is correct then definitely i am gonna accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (Code.days<2) 
 {
   holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.RED);
 }
 else if (Code.days < 5)  
 {
      holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
 }
 else if (Code.days > 8) 
 {
   holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
```